# Eisenstein Series at CM points

Tags: complex-multiplication, eisenstein-series

Suppose that $L= \mathbb{Z}\tau + \mathbb{Z}$ is a lattice with CM. Consider the Eisenstein sum
$$ G_{2k}(L) = \sum_{(m,n)\neq (0,0)} \frac{1}{(m\tau+n)^{2k}}$$
where $k$ is a positive integer greater than 1.

What is known in the literature about the values of these sums? I know they should be algebraic numbers that lie in the Hilbert/ring class field corresponding to the lattice.

Comment: Of course, I meant I'm particularly interested in $k=2$ and $k=3$

Comment: For $k=1$ there are two ways to make sense of the series: Eisenstein summation and Kronecker/Hecke summation. This is explained in Weil's book "Elliptic functions according to Eisenstein and Kronecker".

Comment: Relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311879

Comment: Apologies, I meant $k=2$ and $k=3$. As pointed out in Francois' link, $E_4$ and $E_6$ are known in terms of $j(\tau)$ and $\eta(\tau)$, but are the special values of these functions for CM values of $\tau$, well known?

Comment: I do not know how well you need this to be known. This is not known to me  but it may be known to Don Zagier.

Comment: Ideally as well known as possible. Particularly as an element of the Hilbert class field or ring class field.

Comment: @Rdrr: If you can formulate the question coherently, send it to Don Zagier.